# EntityType has no key defined on column named "NameId"

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

My model has a property defined like this:

```
public string NameId { get; set; }
```

I've read that EF recognizes ID if it's names as `"ID"` or `"somethingID"`. Why it doesn't in my case? It is a primary key in the sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF is giving correct error.

According to EF design, `NameId` will be treated as primary key if your `class` name is `Name`. Otherwise you have to use `[Key]` attribute explicitly.

For Example:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

In the above case `EntityId` will be regarded as primary key because its prefixed with the class name `Entity`